# definition of Cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

let X be RV, and his Cumulative distribution function:

[image]

there is a difference if in my case if $X<x$ ? the definition  is the same?

Comment: $F_X(x)=Pr[X<x]+Pr[X=x]$ so iff $Pr[X=x]=0$ for each $x$ then then $F_X(x)=Pr[X<x]$ for each $x$. In that case you are dealing with a continuous CDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends if $X$ has a probability density function or not.
If it has, no difference, elsewhere it can be different (for example if $X=0$ with probability one).

Comment: If $X$ has a PDF (i.e. the distribution is *absolutely continuous* with respect to the Lebesguemeasure) then its CDF is indeed *continuous*. However, the converse of this is not true in general. There are continuous distributions that have no PDF.